# SSH connection to a machine on boot

Tags: command-line, networking, server, bash, ssh

I have a Raspberry which establish a connection to a remote machine, via ssh, using a SSH Keypair, which allow it to access   without prompting  a password.

My question is this:

How I can do to establish a SSH-connection from the Raspberry to a default remote machine, which has a static IP, and execute a remote command, on Raspberry's boot?
I've tried a lot of solutions, but none of these works!!

1) adding my script to /etc/init.d and then update-rc.d myscript defaults

2) adding into /etc/rc.local file

3) adding into /home/pi/.bashrc file

-----TO EXPLOIT THE AUTOMATIC CONNECTION OF PI TO WIFI_____

4) adding into /etc/network/if-up.d

5) adding by "post-up" command into interfaces file

I have ever fail. This below is my script:

```
#! /bin/sh
ssh remotemachine@ip-address touch success
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe give it a go with cron.

> crontab -e

Add a line:

> @reboot ssh remotemachine@ip-address touch success

If you want to allow some time for the system (and interface) to come online:

> @reboot sleep 60 && ssh remotemachine@ip-address touch success

The interface post-up execution makes more sense, cron is easier but not ideal. For Raspberry experimentation it should be good enough.